# Telethon - Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: python, telethon

I have used this python code to find de chatId:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient('none', 111111, '12a12b12c12d12e12f12g12h') as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.CheckChatInviteRequest(
        hash='AAAAAAAABBBBBBB'
))
print(result.stringify())
```

..and I got this info:

```
ChatInviteAlready(
    chat=Channel(
            id=123456789,
            title='Some channel',
            photo=ChatPhoto(.....
```

Trying to use this id id I'm getting the error:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}
```

I already tried to append "-100" but it didn't work:

```
https://api.telegram.org/<bot>/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=12345678
https://api.telegram.org/<bot>/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=-10012345678
https://api.telegram.org/<bot>/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=10012345678
```

Could you please help me to find the correct way to use the chatId?

Comment: You need to join the chat first. after joining, although botapi is unrelated to telethon, make sure they're the same account. you shouldn't have a problem using id (with -100 prepended) after you join.

Comment: @MustA But I have joined this channel. I'm not the admin, so I can't invite any bot. I already created a private channel to test and I was not able to use Telegram API using the chatId of my own channel

Comment: You can't use the id of a chat you haven't joined. it's just how the api works, the id is only known to you the one who resolved the invite link, the bot can't just interact with a chat it hasn't joined. so "no way" is the answer you need